# Matrix expression- expansion of brackets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm struggling to understand matrices a little and was looking for some guidance.
I have the following expression that I need to expand:

$$ (A-B)^{2} $$

where A and B are (m x n) matrices.

What I attempted so far looked like this

$$ (A-B)^{2} = (A-B)(A-B) = A^{2} - AB - BA + B^{2} $$
$$ = A^{T} A - AB - BA + B^{T}B$$

if A and B are both (m x n) matrices then I would expect the two end terms to be of size (n x m) x (m x n) = (n x n), and the two middle terms to be of size (m x n) x (m x n) = (m x n). These differently shaped matrices clearly cannot be added together. I'm clearly doing something very incorrect here and am looking for pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: $A^2$ and $A^tA$ are two different things, and one of them doesn't exist if $m\ne n$.

Comment: Indeed, $(A-B)^2$ makes no sense if $m\ne n$.

Comment: $(A-B)^2$ does not exist if $n \neq m$.

Comment: Ah, I see, ok, that makes sense - I couldn't see a way forward if m != n. If m == n, then would it be the case that $A^{2} = A^{T}A$?

Comment: No. For square matrices, $A^2$ is in general different from $A^TA$. Consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ for instance.

Comment: $A^2$ is $AA$. Why would you expect $AA$ to equal $A^tA$, P227?